# How to set docker port after Published ports are discarded?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nvidia-docker

I want to use the following method to install tensorflow:

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia --name tensorflow3 -it -p 6006:6006 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

but I get:

> WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode

How to set port?

Comment: Are you sure that's the command you're using? It might be that you have `--network=host` somewhere.

Comment: no, didn't use --network=host. I can't open the jupyter with browser. but if I use the following method , I can open the website: docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx . So I suspect I use the wrong port.